# Migration guide for Schedulers.enableMetrics() in project Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I noticed that `Schedulers.enableMetrics()` got deprecated but I don't know what I should I do to get all my schedulers metered in a typical use case (using Spring Boot application).

Javadoc suggests using timedScheduler but how should it be achieved for Spring Boot?

Answer (score 5):

First off, here are my thoughts on why the `Schedulers.enableMetrics()` approach was deprecated:

---

The previous approach was flawed in several ways:

- intrinsic dependency on the `MeterRegistry#globalRegistry()` without any way of using a different registry.
- wrong level of abstraction and limited instrumentation:

  - it was not the schedulers themselves that were instrumented, but individual `ExecutorService` instances assumed to back the schedulers.
  - schedulers NOT backed by any `ExecutorService` couldn't be instrumented.
  - schedulers backed by MULTIPLE `ExecutorService` (eg. a pool of workers) would produce multiple levels of metrics difficult to aggregate.
  - instrumentation was *all-or-nothing*, potentially polluting metrics backend with metrics from global or irrelevant schedulers.

A deliberate constraint of the new approach is that each `Scheduler` must be explicitly wrapped, which ensures that the correct `MeterRegistry` is used and that metrics are recognizable and aggregated for that particular `Scheduler` (thanks to the mandatory `metricsPrefix`).

---

I'm not a Spring Boot expert, but if you *really* want to instrument all the schedulers including the global ones here is a naive approach that will aggregate data from all the schedulers of same category, demonstrated in a Spring Boot app:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class SchedulersConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Order(1)
        public Scheduler originalScheduler() {
            // For comparison, we can capture a new original Scheduler (which won't be disposed by setFactory, unlike the global ones)
            return Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(4, 100, "compare");
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleMeterRegistry registry() {
            return new SimpleMeterRegistry();
        }

        @Bean
        public Schedulers.Factory instrumentedSchedulers(SimpleMeterRegistry registry) {
            // Let's create a Factory that does the same as the default Schedulers factory in Reactor-Core, but with instrumentation
            return new Schedulers.Factory() {
                @Override
                public Scheduler newBoundedElastic(int threadCap, int queuedTaskCap, ThreadFactory threadFactory, int ttlSeconds) {
                    // The default implementation maps to the vanilla Schedulers so we can delegate to that
                    Scheduler original = Schedulers.Factory.super.newBoundedElastic(threadCap, queuedTaskCap, threadFactory, ttlSeconds);

                    // IMPORTANT NOTE: in this example _all_ the schedulers of the same type will share the same prefix/name
                    // this would especially be problematic if gauges were involved as they replace old gauges of the same name.
                    // Fortunately, for now, TimedScheduler only uses counters, timers and longTaskTimers.
                    String prefix = "my.instrumented.boundedElastic"; // TimedScheduler will add `.scheduler.xxx` to that prefix
                    return Micrometer.timedScheduler(original, registry, prefix);
                }

                @Override
                public Scheduler newParallel(int parallelism, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
                    Scheduler original = Schedulers.Factory.super.newParallel(parallelism, threadFactory);
                    String prefix = "my.instrumented.parallel"; // TimedScheduler will add `.scheduler.xxx` to that prefix
                    return Micrometer.timedScheduler(original, registry, prefix);
                }

                @Override
                public Scheduler newSingle(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
                    Scheduler original = Schedulers.Factory.super.newSingle(threadFactory);
                    String prefix = "my.instrumented.single"; // TimedScheduler will add `.scheduler.xxx` to that prefix
                    return Micrometer.timedScheduler(original, registry, prefix);
                }
            };
        }

        @PreDestroy
        void resetFactories() {
            System.err.println("Resetting Schedulers Factory to default");
            // Later on if we want to disable instrumentation we can reset the Factory to defaults (closing all instrumented schedulers)
            Schedulers.resetFactory();
        }
    }


    @Service
    public static class Demo implements ApplicationRunner {

        final Scheduler forComparison;
        final SimpleMeterRegistry registry;
        final Schedulers.Factory factory;

        Demo(Scheduler forComparison, SimpleMeterRegistry registry, Schedulers.Factory factory) {
            this.forComparison = forComparison;
            this.registry = registry;
            this.factory = factory;

            Schedulers.setFactory(factory);
        }

        public void generateMetrics() {
            Schedulers.boundedElastic().schedule(() -> {});
            Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(4, 100, "bounded1").schedule(() -> {});
            Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(4, 100, "bounded2").schedule(() -> {});
            Micrometer.timedScheduler(
                    forComparison,
                    registry,
                    "my.custom.instrumented.bounded"
            ).schedule(() -> {});
            Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(4, 100, "bounded3").schedule(() -> {});
        }

        public String getCompletedSummary() {
            return Search.in(registry)
                    .name(n -> n.endsWith(".scheduler.tasks.completed"))
                    .timers()
                    .stream()
                    .map(c -> c.getId().getName() + "=" + c.count())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }

        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
            generateMetrics();
            System.err.println(getCompletedSummary());
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
my.instrumented.boundedElastic.scheduler.tasks.completed=4
my.custom.instrumented.bounded.scheduler.tasks.completed=1
```

Notice how the metrics for the four `instrumentedFactory`-produced `Scheduler` are aggregated together.

There's a bit of a hacky workaround for this: by default Schedulers uses `ReactorThreadFactory`, an internal private class which happens to be a `Supplier<String>`, supplying the "simplified name" (ie `toString` but without the configuration options) of the `Scheduler`.

One could use the following method to tentatively extract that name:

```java
static String inferSimpleSchedulerName(ThreadFactory threadFactory, String defaultName) {
    if (!(threadFactory instanceof Supplier)) {
        return defaultName;
    }
    Object supplied = ((Supplier<?>) threadFactory).get();
    if (!(supplied instanceof String)) {
        return defaultName;
    }
    return (String) supplied;
}
```

Which can be applied to eg. the `newParallel` method in the factory:

```java
String simplifiedName = inferSimpleSchedulerName(threadFactory, "para???");
String prefix = "my.instrumented." + simplifiedName; // TimedScheduler will add `.scheduler.xxx` to that prefix
```

This can then be demonstrated by submitting a few tasks to different parallel schedulers in the `Demo#generateMetrics()` part:

```java
Schedulers.parallel().schedule(() -> {});
Schedulers.newParallel("paraOne").schedule(() -> {});
Schedulers.newParallel("paraTwo").schedule(() -> {});
```

And now it prints (blank lines for emphasis):

```
my.instrumented.paraOne.scheduler.tasks.completed=1
my.instrumented.paraTwo.scheduler.tasks.completed=1
my.instrumented.parallel.scheduler.tasks.completed=1

my.custom.instrumented.bounded.scheduler.tasks.completed=1
my.instrumented.boundedElastic.scheduler.tasks.completed=4
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanations. It would be good to update https://github.com/reactor/reactor-monitoring-demo as well